# Find a recurrence relation for the number of bit strings of length n that contain consecutive symbols that are the same

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Here is my attempt:

1. First there is $2 \cdot 2^{n-1}$ ways if string ends with $00$ or $11$.
2. Second there are ways when string end with $10$ or $01$. So it will give us $a(n-1)$ ways to solve remaining part.

So the final answer would be $a(n) = 2^{n-1} + a(n-1)$. Am I right? If it possible could you explain this in your way, because I could not completely understand what I wrote. Thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a string of length $(n-1)$ has consecutive bits that are equal, then this will hold true for any string of length $n$ which is formed by appending a bit onto a valid string with length $n-1$. This is where the $2a(n-1)$ comes from (2 since we get to choose the last digit). Now to make sure we count all possible strings, we need to ensure that we count the strings who’s first $(n-1)$ bits do not fulfill the condition, but where the string fulfills the condition. The only such strings are those with first $n-1$ digits $$1010… \text{ and } 0101…$$ which end in a repeat so there are two such strings. So I think the solution should be $$a(n) = 2a(n-1) +2$$.

Comment: As a follow up, you can check your answer is correct, by solving for a closed form (note that $a(2) = 2$) so any solution which gives you the closed form $a(n) = 2^n - 2$ which is the number of strings minus the number of strings with no repeats should be correct.

Comment: If there is string with length 4 then by brutal counting number of such strings will be 12. By your formula answer is 14

Comment: I don’t see how this is possible, I don’t think there are more strings than $1010$ and $0101$ of length 4 which don’t have consecutive bits (this is because it must start with either 0 or 1 and the remaining bits are forced), and there are $2^4 = 16$ total strings of length 4.

Comment: Maybe missing some variants but let's try count manually. So strings with length 4 are:0000,0010,0001,1001,1000,1100,1111,0100,0111,1101,1110,0011,1011

Comment: Oh turns out I missed some combinations. You are right!